# Abstract classes of anodyne maps (relative to an interval) in a presheaf category are stable under smash products with monomorphisms?

Tags: homotopy-theory, abstract-nonsense

Let $A$ be a small category, and let $X:=Psh(A)$ denote the category of presheaves on $A$.  It is a theorem that for any such category $X$, there exists a small set $M$ of monomorphisms admitting the small object argument such that $LLP(RLP(M))$ is exactly the class of all monomorphisms of $X$.  Recall that a separated segment (a separated interval) is a triple $(I,\partial^0,\partial^1)$ where $\partial^i:*\to I$ (where $*$ denotes the terminal object) and such that the pullback of the diagram $\partial^0:*\hookrightarrow I\hookleftarrow *:\partial^1$ is the empty presheaf.

This triple defines a functorial cylinder $(I\times(-),\partial^0\times id_{(-)}, \partial^1\times id_{(-)},\sigma\times id_{(-)})$ where $\sigma:I\to *$ is the terminal map.  By abuse of notation, we will write for any object $P$ in $X$, $\partial^0_P:=\partial^0\times id_P, \partial^1_P:=\partial^1\times id_P$ and $\sigma_P:= \sigma\times id_P$.  Since $X$ is a presheaf topos, we can see easily that given any monomorphism $K\to L$ in $X$, the square:

$$\begin{matrix}K&\hookrightarrow &L\\
\downarrow&&\downarrow\\
I\times K&\hookrightarrow&I\times L\end{matrix}$$

(where the vertical arrows are the induced maps $\partial^0_K$ and $\partial^0_L$, or $\partial^1_K$ and $\partial^1_L$) is cartesian and is composed exclusively of monomorphisms.  Because of this very fine property, we may define $I\times K \cup \{i\}\times L$ to be the subobject of $I\times L$ given by the apparent inclusion of the pushout where $i$ depends on the $\partial^i$ appearing in the above diagram.  Adding to our list of suggestive notation, we define the map $\partial I:= *\coprod *$ considered as a subobject of $I$ by the canonical map from the coproduct $(\partial^0,\partial^1)$ (similarly, we define $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ to be the subobjects corresponding to the obvious maps (in this notation, $\partial I = \{0\}\coprod \{1\}$).  We denote the previously mentioned inclusion $(\partial^0,\partial^1)$ by $b:\partial I\hookrightarrow I$, and as with the other distinguished maps, putting a subscript gives the obvious piece of the natural transformation.

Given any two morphisms $f:A\to A',g:B\to B'$ in $X$, define their smash product $f\wedge g:A\times B'\coprod_{A\times B} A'\times B \to A'\times B'$.  Note that the smash product gives a monoidal product on $Arr(X)$ (the unit being the inclusion of the empty presheaf into the terminal one).

Given a separated segment $I$ in $X$, define a class of anodyne morphisms relative to $I$ to be a class $An$ of monomorphisms of $X$ satisfying the following three conditions:

$An_0:$ There exists a small set $S$ of monomorphisms such that $An=LLP(RLP(S))$.
$An_1:$ For any monomorphism $f:K\hookrightarrow L$, the smash products $\partial^i\wedge f$ are elements of $An$ for $i=0,1$.
$An_2:$ For any $f\in An$, the smash product $b\wedge f$ is an element of  $An$ (recall again that $b:\partial I\to I$ is the canonical inclusion).

Question:  Given any category of presheaves $X$, any separated segment $I$ on $X$, and any class of morphisms $An$ anodyne with respect to $I$, is it the case that given any monomorphism $f$ in $X$ and any anodyne morphism $g$ in $An$ that $f\wedge g\in An$? If this is true would you mind sketching a proof?

Comment: In your second sentence you look like you need $M = S$ :)

Comment: I picked a different variable and forgot to change all instances.  Thanks!

Comment: I think that explaining where this comes from (namely, Cisinski's work, right?) and giving a reference could help the non-expert but interested readers and thus improve the question (just my two cents).  

Comment: Dear Jonathan, yes, you are exactly correct! There's a copy of the book (Astérisque 308 - Les préfaisceaux commes modèles des types d'homotopie) somewhere on his website, but I don't remember exactly where, since it's not visible from his publications page. In absence of the link, I can definitely at least say that it's top-notch! I do not think that this specific question is addressed in the book, but the background provided above is roughly the content of the first few pages of chapter 1.3.  (For those of you who aren't familiar with it, the machinery developed in that section is a very...

Comment: powerful method of building model structures on presheaf categories. For instance, it follows from the resolution of this question that we can generate the model structures for quasi-categories, right fibrations, and left fibrations of simplicial sets by including (up to freely adjoining contractible simplices, a exactly one single extra morphism to the minimal homotopy theory for simplicial sets.  For right fibrations, this is exactly the map $\{1\}:\Delta^0\hookrightarrow \Delta^1$ the inclusion of the terminal vertex into the 1-simplex.  

Comment: Dear Harry: The link to Cisinski's publications page is http://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~dcisinsk/publications.html. The fifth link points towards a copy of the book: http://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~dcisinsk/ast.pdf. Anodyne extensions in this general setting were already mentioned in "Théories homotopiques dans les topos" (second link of the publications page) but since I'm not familiar with the theory I don't know whether it was their first occurrence in the literature. 

Comment: Oh, hah! That's actually hilarious.  I have my screen oriented vertically, and it just cut off the right side of the page with all of the pdf links.

Comment: Anyway, looking at the second paper you mentioned, I believe that paper was based on part of his thesis and reappears essentially unchanged although substantially expanded in the book.  The first five sections of that paper are pretty much exactly what later appears in the book (1.1 - 1.5), although the book is substantially updated, and at least according to the summary paper by Jardine, the book contains a large number of substantial new results that did not appear in the thesis of the same name.  

Comment: An interesting fact is that the original paper defined a class of anodyne extensions to be a certain construction on a set of maps.  It is then a lemma to show that this agrees with the notion that appears in the later work (particularly the book).

Comment: "I have my screen oriented vertically" Ok now I get it.

Comment: I remember Maltsiniotis is thanked in the "Préambule" of Cisinski's book: « en particulier, il a amélioré la définition d'extension anodine en dégageant une axiomatique simple ». 

Comment: @Martin: You don't know the half of it.  I always wondered why it was so hard to find links on his website.  Now I know why!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This condition is equivalent to the following condition:

The class $\mathrm{An}=\mathrm{An}(\Lambda_I(S))$ of anodynes generated by a small set $S$ of monomorphisms with respect to the cylinder $I$ is closed under finite Cartesian products with objects of $X=\mathrm{Psh}(A)$.  That is, for any anodyne $f:K\hookrightarrow L$, and any object $B$ in $X$, the map $B\times f: B\times K\hookrightarrow B\times L$ is also anodyne, or equivalently, that the $A$-localizer $W(An)=W_I(S)=W(\Lambda_I(S))$ (which is accessible since $S$ is a small set)  generated by $An$ is a Cartesian localizer.

This follows from [Corollary 1.3.58](http://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~dcisinsk/ast.pdf#Page=68), which in particular, says that $An$ has the following property:

If $u,v$ are composable monomorphisms in $X$ with composite $vu$ such that $u\in An$ and $vu\in An$, then $v\in An$.

Suppose that $f:K\hookrightarrow L$ is anodyne and $g:B\hookrightarrow C$ is any monomorphism.

We have the evident diagram:

$$\begin{matrix}B\times K&\hookrightarrow &C\times K\\
\downarrow&&\downarrow\\
B\times L&\hookrightarrow&C\times L\end{matrix}$$

In which the vertical maps are anodyne (by assumption).

Pushing out with respect to the top left corner, we get another diagram:

$$\begin{matrix}B\times K&\hookrightarrow &C\times K\\
\downarrow&&\downarrow\\
B\times L&\hookrightarrow&P\end{matrix}$$

and a unique map $P\hookrightarrow C\times L$ making things commute as they should.  Notice now that $$C\times K \hookrightarrow C\times L = C\times K \hookrightarrow P \hookrightarrow C\times L.$$  However, the LHS is anodyne, and the map $B\times K\hookrightarrow P$ is anodyne as well, being a pushout of an anodyne map.  Restating this, we see that $vu$ is anodyne and that $u$ is anodyne.  Therefore, it follows that $v=f\wedge g:P\hookrightarrow B\times L$ is itself anodyne.

Also, it turns out that this answer holds in the slightly more general case whenever $I$ is a "good functorial cylinder" for $X$.

As the localizer $W(An)$ is accessible (by the axioms for a class of anodynes) and therefore is the class of weak equivalences for a model structure on $X$ where the cofibrations are the monomorphisms, this is equivalent to asking that the associated model structure is Cartesian-closed, since it implies that the fibrant objects are precisely those objects $B$ such that for every anodyne morphism $K\hookrightarrow L$, the induced map on internal function objects $B^L\to B^K$ is a trivial fibration in the associated model structure.